# What's special about gcc flags that start with "tree"?

Tags: gcc, compiler-flags

There are a lot of [optimization settings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) starting with `tree`. Some are:

```
-ftree-builtin-call-dce
-ftree-ccp
-ftree-ch
-ftree-copyrename
-ftree-dce
-ftree-dominator-opts
-ftree-dse
-ftree-ter
```

What's special about those flags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They all work with the tree representation of your source code.

Not sure exactly how GCC does it, but in general a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) will parse your code and turn it into an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), [parse tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) or similar structure. These optimizations work on that tree. Later, the tree will be used to generate the machine code.